# Extracting Domain Suffixes and Computing Hit Counts in Scala

Tags: scala

Looking for some suggestions for optimizing this solution in vanilla Scala to a problem I ran into in a textbook:

Let's say you are given some data like this:

```scala
val counts = Array(
  "900,google.com", 
  "60,mail.yahoo.com", 
  "40,sports.yahoo.com", 
  "50,mobile.sports.yahoo.com", 
  "3,en.wikipedia.org"
)
```

The first value represents the number of hits that domain received. What I want to do is be able to rollup the counts of each domain and each subdomain belonging to it. So the output should look something like:

```scala
res = List(
  ("com", 1050),
  ("google.com", 900),
  ("yahoo.com", 150),
  ("sports.yahoo.com", 90),
  ("mail.yahoo.com", 60),
  ("mobile.sports.yahoo.com", 50),
  ("sports.yahoo.com", 40),
  ("org", 3),
  ("en.wikipedia.org",3)
)
```

The below code works, at least on the provided data:

```scala
object Solution {

  val counts = Array(
    "900,google.com",
    "60,mail.yahoo.com",
    "10,mobile.sports.yahoo.com",
    "40,sports.yahoo.com",
    "10,stackoverflow.com",
    "2,en.wikipedia.org",
    "1,es.wikipedia.org",
    "1,mobile.sports"
  )

  case class DomainMapEntry(count: Int, suffix: String)


  private def extractSuffixes(str: String): List[String] =
    str.split('.').foldLeft(List.empty[String]) { (acc, part) =>
      part :: acc.map(rest => s"$rest.$part")
    }

  // split each entry in the array, extract suffixes and pair with count.
  private def createDomainMap(str: String): List[Option[DomainMapEntry]] =
    str.split(",").take(2).toList match {
      case h :: t :: Nil => extractSuffixes(t).map(suffix => Some(DomainMapEntry(Integer.parseInt(h), suffix)))
      case _             => List(None)
    }

  // create a map of suffixes and counts, flatten and group by suffixes,
  // sum the grouped counts, and sort in reverse
  def parseCounts(arr: Array[String]) =
    arr
      .map(createDomainMap)
      .flatten
      .flatten
      .groupBy(_.suffix)
      .mapValues(_.map(_.count).sum)
      .toList
      .sortBy(-_._2)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = println(parseCounts(counts).mkString("\n"))
}
```

But, I feel like it could be significantly improved. Obviously, the `case class` could just be a tuple, but algorithmically I feel like I am missing something, also I am not too worried about malformed data, just an exercise.

1. Could I more elegantly (simply, with better performance) extract suffixes with counts?
2. That double `flatten` call, maybe a code smell?
3. splitting and rejoining to create suffix patterns seems janky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to approach a task like this. Here's one alternative.

```scala
counts.flatMap{ str =>
  val Array(num,domain) = str.split(",")
  domain.split("\\.")
        .tails
        .collect{case d if d.nonEmpty => (d.mkString("."), num.toInt)}
}.groupMapReduce(_._1)(_._2)(_+_)  //Scala 2.13.0
 .toList
 .sortBy(-_._2)

//res0: List[(String, Int)] = List((com,1050)
//                               , (google.com,900)
//                               , (yahoo.com,150)
//                               , (sports.yahoo.com,90)
//                               , (mail.yahoo.com,60)
//                               , (mobile.sports.yahoo.com,50)
//                               , (wikipedia.org,3)
//                               , (org,3)
//                               , (en.wikipedia.org,3))
```

Note that this doesn't screen for bad input so that would have to be added or done beforehand.

Comment: Thank you and glad I asked. I learned three things from your submission, scala's pattern matching works outside case statements like that. `tails`, and another cool thing about 2.13 `groupMapReduce` which should help around some of the weirdness that `mapValues` supposedly has. Cheers!